# Apache Hive How to round off to 2 decimal places?

Tags: hadoop, hiveql

Actually I'm looking for more details about the sum function in Apache Hive.
Until now, I understood that I can specify the number of digits after the dot:

```
val DECIMAL(18, 3)
```

But what I can not find is the precision scale in case of sum.
If I add 2 decimals with a precision scale of 3 for example, what will be the return of the sum function? My precision scale will be preserved?
The result will be truncated or rounded?
What have I missed?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Just round it to as many decimal places as you want.

```
select round(SUM(150.100 + 127.0090), 2);
```

Output of above will be:-

```
277.11
```

Comment: I'm using Hive (version 1.1.0-cdh5.10.1). Trying your query through HUE, it returns 277.11000000000001. Then I tried it through beeline and I got the correct result (277.11). Even writing the result to a file works fine. I think it's a bug with HUE UI!